# Latent Dirichlet Allocation - definitions

Tags: machine-learning, probability, self-study, generative-models

I am self-studying the article on LDA by Blei, Ng and Jordan (https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/BleiNgJordan2003.pdf). at the start of the second section - the following definitions are given:

to test my understanding - am i right to visualize that each word vector w would look like e.g. (0,0,1,0,0,..), that a document **w** would be V times N matrix of 0's and 1's (with each column summing up to one) and that the corpus would hence be a 3 dimensional array with dimensions V times N times M ? or am i misunderstanding this? Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you described it is right and that's how it's explained in the paper but it's not the way that any of the algorithm's modern implementations handle it. Rather, what happens is that the word vector is composed of symbols (almost always represented as integers) where each symbol indexes a word. For example, if there is a corpus of four words {"bacon", "porcetta","jowls","sausage"} then the document vector corresponding to the sentence "jowls jowls sausage bacon" could be represented by the vector { 3, 3, 4, 1}. So, if we have M documents and (let's assume uniform document length) each document is N words long, our corpus is an MxN matrix. If the document length is not uniform, then you will represent this as an array of vectors of differing length.

One question you might have then is "well, what does the vocabulary mean then?" It's really just a list of your symbols. For my example above, the vocabulary would be {1 2 3 4} and you would also want to keep a dictionary of mappings between integers and words.

So, just to recap: documents are vectors of length $n$ which can be either uniform or vary between documents. The corpus is of size $M * N$. Integers are used to represent words. If you are skeptical, check out the code on their webpage at http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/lda-c/ . If you download the c-lda.tgz archive and inspect the file lda-data.c, you can see that they used integers for words.